# Calculate SNR in single image in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, noise

I have this image:

[image: noisy image]

I want to calculate SNR in it. For this i used code:

```
img=imread('noicy.JPG');
img=double(img(:));
ima=max(img(:));
imi=min(img(:));
ims=std(img(:));
snr=20*log10((ima-imi)./ims)
```

Is that correct code to calculate SNR?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The definition of SNR can be found [here](http://bigwww.epfl.ch/sage/soft/snr/) or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio_(imaging)):

Both the standard and the industry definition can be used (`10log(x)` and `20log(x)`). [check this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel#Definition)

now, the `signal` is equal to the mean of the pixel values (`mean(img(:))`) and the `noise` is the standard deviation or error value of the pixel values (`std(img(:))`).

You may use either the ratio or the `SNR=10*log10(signal/noise)` to express the result in decibel.

Comment: Thanks, but Is the value of this parameter is the relative or absolute?