# What are the correct way to calculate the SNR with these images in MATLAB?

Tags: performance, matlab, image-processing, filtering, signal-processing

Currently I am trying to figure out the Signal to Noise Ratio of a set of images as a way of gauging the performance of my deconvolution (filtering algorithms). I Have a set of images like the one below, which show the image, before and after the algorithm:

[image]

Now, I have discovered quite a few ways of judging the performance. One of these is to use the formula for the SNR of an image, where the signal is the original image and the noise is the filtered image. Another method, as described by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699903/calculate-snr-in-single-image-in-matlab) question, goes about figuring out the SNR from the singular image itself. This way, I can compare the SNR ratios that I get for both images and get an all new altogether.

Therefore, my question lies in the fact that, the resources on the internet are confusing and I do not know about the **"correct"** way of measuring the SNR of these images and using it as a performance metric.

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to compare, and what you deem as "signal" and "noise". In your first method, you are effectively calculating the error(or difference) between image 1 and image 2 where you assume image 2 was tinted by noise but image 1 was not (this is also a sort of signal to distortion ratio). Therefore, this measurement is relative.

Comment: In the second method based on the link you posted, you are assuming that noise is present in both images but at different levels and you are measuring it against each individual image - or in other words, you are measuring the standard deviation of each individual image, which is not relative. I add that the second measurement is usually used to compare results generated from the same source, while method 1 is usually used to compare the performance of the method that generated image 2 from image 1.

Comment: @GameOfThrows That's the answer that I was looking for! Put it down and I will accept it. Please include where, you would use both of the techniques to measure the SNR and which image goes where in terms of the equation for SNR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what you are trying to compare, and what you deem as "**signal**" and "**noise**". In your first method, you are effectively calculating the error(or difference) between image 1 and image 2 where you assume image 2 was tinted by noise but image 1 was not (this is also a sort of signal to distortion ratio). Therefore, **this measurement is relative and it measures the performance of your method of transformation from Original to Target** (or distortion technique), but not the image itself. For example a new type of encrypting filter generated image 2 from image 1 and you want to measure how different the images are to work out the performance of your filter.

In the second method based on the link you posted, you are assuming that noise is present in both images but at different levels and you are measuring it against each individual image - or in other words, **you are measuring the standard deviation of each individual image**, which is not relative.The second measurement is usually used to **compare results generated from the same source**, i.e. an experiment produces N images of the same object in a controlled environment and you want to measure, for example the amount of noise present at the scene (you would use this method to work out the covariance of noise to enable you to control the experiment environment).

Comment: just a side note: Are there any other ways of approaching the measurement of signal to noise ratio when it comes to these two pictures?

Comment: There are loads of other measurements for different field of studies, but not really for Signal vs Noise, more for things like Signal vs Distortion, Signal vs Interference and even the RMSE is used to compare between 2 images. Noise is often used to describe everything that went wrong with the image, but it is not always the case. The noise is usually what happened before digitization (photon shot noise, salt and pepper noise etc) and digital processing that happens after digitization are sometimes referred as artifact error - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artifact_(error)